# Field with auto_complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, autocomplete

newbe question here.

I've inherited a rails project and been asked to change some chunk of code, but I have a very little experience in Ruby and Rails (I am an objective-c with a PHP background developper)

So the first stuff I have to had is a textfield with an auto complete mode. Actually my code has this code for the auto completed text field :

**registration_controller.rb**

```
    def auto_complete_for_training_title
    puts "auto_complete_for_training_title"

    current_locale = params[:locale].to_s
    if current_locale == 'en' then
      if current_user.member then
        Locale.set current_user.member.written_language
      else
        Locale.set 'fr'
      end
    end

    @trainings = Training.find(:all, :conditions => ["((title LIKE ? OR fso_id LIKE ?) and is_private = 0", '%' + params[:training][:title] + '%', '%' + params[:training][:title] + '%'])
    puts @trainings.count
    render :partial => 'complete_ajax_own_function_training'
   end
```

In the view, the text field is created like this :

```
<% form_for :sortRegistration, { :url => { :action => 'index'} } do |f| %>

    <p><label><%= "Display registrations by training".t %> :</label>
    <%= text_field_with_auto_complete :training, :title, { :size => 50, :tabindex => 1 }, 
                    { :select => 'mon_titre',
                      :after_update_element => "function(element,val)
                       {
                         var nodes = val.select(['.value_title']) || [];
                         if(nodes.length>0)
                            {
                            $('sortRegistration_training_id').value = Element.collectTextNodes(nodes[0], 'value_title');
                            }
                        }"
                    }
    %></p>

<input id="sortRegistration_training_id" name="sortRegistration[training_id]" type="hidden" size="20" value="" /> 

<% end %>
```

If I copy / paste the code, only one textField works, I've tried to change some parameters but still not changing something.

P.S. As I said I am new in the RoR, I do not know if you need more code for help me so please, feel free to ask more, I will edit my question

Comment: what text field doesn't work. are there any errors?

Comment: To achieve the autocomplete functionality you can integrate jquery tokeninput here is the link http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: @roninblade When I type something in the textfield, there is no auto_complete, I mean the "pop" menu does not appear.

Comment: @Kiran Kumara Thank you, but it seems that your link is not the same method which is used in the project, isnt it?

Comment: put in the actual code instead of an example. point out which one is working and which one isn't.

Comment: The controller is pretty huge, more than 1k2 lines, I am just looking for a clue or something for add another autocompleted text field which contains the same "autocomplete" than code above, simply copy / past it does not work

Comment: yes its different one, i guess you are trying to achieve the auto-completion , in this case you can define one text_field and for that text field you can integrate the token input as provided on demo link.